# Linker error: ld symbols not found

Tags: c++

I have a class defined as follows:

```
// grid_search.h
template<typename Element, typename Solution, typename Oracle>
class grid_search : public OptimizerInterface<Element, Solution, Oracle> {
private:
    // ...
public:
    virtual Solution search(const SpaceInterface<Element>& space, Oracle oracle);
};
```

and I implement it in `grid_search.cc`. Now I use it like this:

```
// needed extra definitions 
typedef double (*oracle_f)(vector<int>&);
class TestSpace : public SpaceInterface<int> { /* ... */ }
static double f(vector<int>& x) { return 0.0; } // what ever f

// setup a search space and run the grid search
TestSpace space(/* ... */);
GridSearch<int, vector<int>, oracle_f> *optimizer = new GridSearch<int, vector<int>, oracle_f>();
optimizer->search(space, f);
```

Then the linker error is (note that everything compiles and the grid_search.cc is found fine):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"GridSearch<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, double (*)(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)>::search(SpaceInterface<int> const&, double (*)(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&))", referenced from:
    vtable for GridSearch<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, double (*)(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)> in grid_search.cc.o
```

I have reviewed it several times but can't figure out what the root of this error is ...

Comment: `search` is not implemented. Or the implementation is not visible.

Comment: Are you putting the implementation in a `.cpp` file by any chance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template function definitions usually need to be in the header file, not a .cc file.

Comment: Indeed, this bites me from time to time again :) sry.